# what characters should be escaped in sql string parameters

Tags: sql, ado.net, objectdatasource

I need a complete list of characters that should be escaped in sql string parameters to prevent exceptions. I assume that I need to replace all the offending characters with the escaped version before I pass it to my ObjectDataSource filter parameter.

Comment: Why aren't you using parameterized SQL with bind variables?  If you use bind variables, you never need to escape anything.

Comment: I decided not to use a parameterized SQL with bind variables because I have a variable number of parameters.

Comment: Is there not a Parameters collection? It's great for a variable number of parameters.

Comment: So you're rolling your own, risking SQL injection, etc?

Comment: I was looking for a simple solution

Comment: You can still create your SQL based on the amount of parameters, and still get the benefit of the use of parameters

Comment: hi, just post your method how you create your sql statement, i'm sure people will show you how to do it correct and clean and without any string replacements.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105643/help-production-db-was-sql-injected  

That's what you get when you "look for a simple solution" ........

Comment: I would like someone to explain how you do a SQL injection on a ObjectDataSource filter.

Answer (score 3):

No, the ObjectDataSource will handle all the escaping for you.  Any parametrized query will also require no escaping.

Comment: This is not a yes or no question bro

Comment: It is to a certain extent.  You said "I assume that I need to replace all the offending characters" and this is not true.  If you don't need to replace offending characters then you don't need a list of them either.

Comment: So you are saying that it is not my assumption?

Comment: Well it is not for me to make a ruling on *your* assumption as it is yours alone.  What I *am* saying however is that your assumption that you clearly stated is incorrect.

Comment: Can you or anyone who up voted your answer show me how to do a parameterized filter with a ObjectDataSource?

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, in 99% of the cases where someone thinks they need to ask this question, they are doing it wrong. Parameterization is the way to go. If you really need to escape yourself, try to find out if your DB access library offers a function for this (for example, MySQL has `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Comment: In this case the others are wrong. I am trying to filter not select. It never touches the database so there is no threat of injection attack. Also a ObjectDataSource doesn't offer parameterized filter expressions. It only offers placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Books online:
Search for String Literals:

String Literals

A string literal consists of zero or more characters surrounded by quotation marks. If a string contains quotation marks, these must be escaped in order for the expression to parse. Any two-byte character except \x0000 is permitted in a string, because the \x0000 character is the null terminator of a string.

Strings can include other characters that require an escape sequence. The following table lists escape sequences for string literals.

\a
 Alert

\b
 Backspace

\f
 Form feed

\n
 New line

\r
 Carriage return

\t
 Horizontal tab

\v
 Vertical tab

\"
 Quotation mark

\
 Backslash

\xhhhh
 Unicode character in hexadecimal notation

Comment: I am looking for a list of characters that cause a SQL string to malfunction. These all seem to be SQL string friendly.

Comment: In reference to my last comment. Some of the characters are used for SQL injection attacks but since it is questionable whether or not you can actually achieve one through a ObjectDataSource FilterExpression I'm not worried about them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I used to get rid of apostrophes.  You could do the same thing with other offending characters that you run into. (example in VB.Net)

```
Dim companyFilter = Trim(Me.ddCompany.SelectedValue)

If (Me.ddCompany.SelectedIndex > 0) Then
      filterString += String.Format("LegalName like '{0}'", companyFilter.Replace("'", "''"))
End If

Me.objectDataSource.FilterExpression = filterString

Me.displayGrid.DataBind()
```